# ManifestInvalidRevisionError while downloading AOSP code

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I am trying to download AOSP code. Repo sync is failing with below error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/': Could not resolve host: android.googlesource.com
error: Cannot fetch platform/frameworks/base from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base
Fetching projects: 100% (784/784), done.
Checking out projects:  57% (447/784) platform/frameworks/averror: Cannot checkout platform/frameworks/base: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision master in platform/frameworks/base not found
error: in `sync`: revision master in platform/frameworks/base not found
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Could+not+resolve+host%3A+android.googlesource.com

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari : The link has solutions for network related errors. I couldn't find any solution for ManifestInvalidRevisionError.

Comment: If you solve the network error, then this error should go away

Comment: Okay. I will try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating curl binary and restarting the PC, the sync error is resolved.